# R ggplot2 / dot plots with categorial y-axis: Summarizing and showing number of observations within given ranges of linear x-axis for each category

Tags: r, ggplot2, count, categories, scatter-plot

```
library(tidyverse)

corSpear_values_PdK_vs_Bands_longf_withoutAB <- corSpear_values_PdK_vs_Bands_withoutAB %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = 5:24, names_to = "band_corSpear")
corSpear_values_PdK_vs_Bands_longf2_withoutAB <- corSpear_values_PdK_vs_Bands_longf_withoutAB %>%
  filter (str_detect(band_corSpear, "_Rho$")) #%>%

corSpear_values_PdK_vs_Bands_longf2_withoutAB_df <- data.frame(corSpear_values_PdK_vs_Bands_longf2_withoutAB)

ggplot(corSpear_values_PdK_vs_Bands_longf2_withoutAB_df, aes(x=value, y=band_corSpear, color = factor(Site_ID):factor(Spot_Nr))) +  # Tip: for subsetting by more than one class take subset(loopsubset_created_S03, Class_Derived %in% c("WW","WF"))
  #geom_point(alpha=0.9, size = 0.01) +
  geom_jitter(alpha=0.3, size = 1, width = 0.0, height = 0.1) +
  #position_jitter(seed = 1)+
  coord_cartesian(xlim = c(-1,1)) +
  labs(x= paste("Spearman-correlation per band [PdKeyt / reflection]"))
```

The above code calculates a jittered dot plot of correlation values from my data. (Correlation between the reflection of 10 spectral bands against one other variable over time. Each dot marks the correlation at one of about 250 geographic sampling points). You'll find a `dput` of the data = df `corSpear_values_PdK_vs_Bands_withoutAB` at the end of the post.

Here the plot with a rough sketch anticipating my intention:
[image]

Additionally the code generates a table of the frequency per correlation value range. There are 8 ranges:

- 0.00 - 0.50
- 0.50 - 0.75
- 0.75 - 0.90
- 0.90 - 1.00
- each for negative and positive range

```
 A tibble: 10 x 9
   band_corSpear Rho_m100m090 Rho_m090m075 Rho_m075m050 Rho_m050_000 Rho__000p050 Rho_p050p075 Rho_p075p090 Rho_p090p100
   <chr>                <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>
 1 B01_Blu_Rho              0            0            0            0            2           18           39            4
 2 B02_Grn_Rho              0            0            0            0            0            1           26           36
 3 B03_Red_Rho              0            0            0            0            0            4            8           51
 4 B04_RE1_Rho              0            0            0            0            1           15           21           26
 5 B05_RE2_Rho              0            0            0            4           41            7            9            2
 6 B06_RE3_Rho              0            0            0            8           41           12            2            0
 7 B07_BNR_Rho              0            0            0            1           44           14            3            1
 8 B08_NIR_Rho              0            0            4           38           19            1            1            0
 9 B09_SW1_Rho             28           33            1            1            0            0            0            0
10 B10_SW2_Rho             28           28            6            1            0            0            0            0
```

**My question:**
Now, I would like to display these numbers (with ranges) on my plot. But at this point I am at the edge of my R / ggplot knowledge. Could anybody help me with the code, please? At least by showing me the right direction!?

<sub>Please note:
 1) I would not stick to curly brackets, i.e. as long as ranges are distinguishable other methods are welcome as well 
2) In contrary to my sketch I would prefer no/blank entries if number is zero</sub>

Here the table:

```
 A tibble: 10 x 9
   band_corSpear Rho_m100m090 Rho_m090m075 Rho_m075m050 Rho_m050_000 Rho__000p050 Rho_p050p075 Rho_p075p090 Rho_p090p100
   <chr>                <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>        <int>
 1 B01_Blu_Rho              0            0            0            0            2           18           39            4
 2 B02_Grn_Rho              0            0            0            0            0            1           26           36
 3 B03_Red_Rho              0            0            0            0            0            4            8           51
 4 B04_RE1_Rho              0            0            0            0            1           15           21           26
 5 B05_RE2_Rho              0            0            0            4           41            7            9            2
 6 B06_RE3_Rho              0            0            0            8           41           12            2            0
 7 B07_BNR_Rho              0            0            0            1           44           14            3            1
 8 B08_NIR_Rho              0            0            4           38           19            1            1            0
 9 B09_SW1_Rho             28           33            1            1            0            0            0            0
10 B10_SW2_Rho             28           28            6            1            0            0            0            0
```

Here the dput:

```
dput(corSpear_values_PdK_vs_Bands_withoutAB)
structure(list(Site_ID = c("C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D",  
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", "D", 
"D", "D", "D", "D"), Spot_Nr = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "3", "3", "3", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "1", "1", "1", "1", "1", 
"1", "1", "1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", "2", 
"3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", 
"4", "4", "4", "4", "4"), Transkt_Nr = c("1", "1", "2", "3", 
"4", "5", "6", "1", "2", "2", "3", "4", "4", "5", "6", "6", "1", 
"2", "2", "3", "4", "4", "5", "6", "6", "3", "6", "1", "1", "2", 
"3", "3", "4", "5", "5", "6", "1", "1", "2", "3", "3", "4", "5", 
"5", "6", "1", "1", "2", "3", "3", "4", "5", "5", "6", "1", "2", 
"2", "3", "4", "4", "5", "6", "6"), Point_Nr = c("8", "9", "9", 
"9", "8", "8", "9", "10", "10", "9", "11", "11", "10", "11", 
"12", "13", "13", "11", "14", "13", "14", "12", "15", "15", "16", 
"9", "9", "7", "6", "9", "9", "8", "11", "11", "9", "11", "7", 
"11", "9", "9", "11", "10", "12", "13", "13", "9", "8", "9", 
"10", "8", "9", "10", "8", "8", "4", "6", "7", "10", "9", "11", 
"12", "12", "14"), B01_Blu_Rho = c(0.71429, 0.9, 0.9, 0.8, 0.5, 
0.5, 0.71429, 0.88571, 0.88571, 0.9, 0.88571, 0.88571, 0.88571, 
0.71429, 0.71429, 0.81168, 0.71429, 0.94286, 0.6, 0.71429, 0.71429, 
0.88571, 0.82857, 0.71429, 0.71429, 0.8, 0.87208, 0.85, 0.67857, 
0.83333, 0.78571, 0.67857, 0.78571, 0.85, 0.78571, 0.67857, 0.82009, 
0.64286, 0.78571, 0.88754, 0.88754, 0.8997, 0.88754, 0.8693, 
0.88754, 0.75, 0.82143, 0.82143, 0.75, 0.78571, 0.75, 0.94286, 
0.78571, 0.71429, 0.89362, 0.8997, 0.85356, 0.84499, 0.8693, 
0.85107, 0.88754, 0.91186, 0.93617), B01_Blu_pvalSpear = c(0.13611, 
0.083333, 0.083333, 0.13333, 0.45, 0.45, 0.13611, 0.033333, 0.033333, 
0.083333, 0.033333, 0.033333, 0.033333, 0.13611, 0.13611, 0.049858, 
0.13611, 0.016667, 0.24167, 0.13611, 0.13611, 0.033333, 0.058333, 
0.13611, 0.13611, 0.13333, 0.053854, 0.0060736, 0.10952, 0.0082672, 
0.027927, 0.10952, 0.027927, 0.0060736, 0.048016, 0.10952, 0.0067875, 
0.13889, 0.027927, 0.00060967, 0.00060967, 0.00039167, 0.00060967, 
0.001087, 0.00060967, 0.06627, 0.034127, 0.034127, 0.06627, 0.048016, 
0.06627, 0.016667, 0.048016, 0.088095, 0.00049187, 0.00039167, 
0.0034182, 0.0020858, 0.001087, 0.0017911, 0.00060967, 0.00023714, 
6.7189e-05), B02_Grn_Rho = c(0.94286, 0.9, 0.9, 0.9, 0.8, 0.8, 
0.88571, 0.94286, 0.94286, 0.9, 0.94286, 0.94286, 0.94286, 0.94286, 
0.88571, 0.94286, 0.94286, 0.82857, 0.94286, 0.88571, 0.88571, 
0.88571, 0.82857, 0.94286, 0.71429, 0.9, 0.9, 0.96667, 0.92857, 
0.93333, 0.97619, 0.92857, 0.95238, 0.96235, 0.91896, 0.92857, 
0.92051, 0.92857, 0.90476, 0.96657, 0.98481, 0.98481, 0.98481, 
0.96657, 0.97265, 0.89286, 0.89286, 0.89286, 0.92857, 0.89286, 
0.89286, 0.94286, 0.89286, 0.89286, 0.8693, 0.9301, 0.93725, 
0.91186, 0.89362, 0.89362, 0.89362, 0.92402, 0.96049), B02_Grn_pvalSpear = c(0.016667, 
0.083333, 0.083333, 0.083333, 0.13333, 0.13333, 0.033333, 0.016667, 
0.016667, 0.083333, 0.016667, 0.016667, 0.016667, 0.016667, 0.033333, 
0.016667, 0.016667, 0.058333, 0.016667, 0.033333, 0.033333, 0.033333, 
0.058333, 0.016667, 0.13611, 0.083333, 0.083333, 0.00016534, 
0.006746, 0.00074956, 0.00039683, 0.006746, 0.0011409, 3.2859e-05, 
0.0034366, 0.006746, 0.0004311, 0.006746, 0.0045635, 5.2481e-06, 
2.2888e-07, 2.2888e-07, 2.2888e-07, 5.2481e-06, 2.3689e-06, 0.012302, 
0.012302, 0.012302, 0.006746, 0.012302, 0.012302, 0.016667, 0.012302, 
0.012302, 0.001087, 9.5961e-05, 0.00019163, 0.00023714, 0.00049187, 
0.00049187, 0.00049187, 0.00013295, 1.0163e-05), B03_Red_Rho = c(0.94286, 
0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 0.9, 0.94286, 0.94286, 0.94286, 0.9, 0.94286, 
0.94286, 0.94286, 0.94286, 0.94286, 0.94286, 0.94286, 0.94286, 
0.94286, 0.94286, 0.94286, 0.94286, 0.94286, 0.94286, 0.94286, 
0.9, 0.9, 0.98333, 0.96429, 0.83333, 0.90476, 0.96429, 0.90476, 
0.88333, 0.96429, 0.96429, 0.95398, 0.96429, 0.97619, 0.97873, 
0.97873, 0.97873, 0.97873, 0.97873, 0.97873, 1, 0.96429, 0.96429, 
0.92857, 0.96429, 0.96429, 0.94286, 0.96429, 0.96429, 0.96049, 
0.85715, 0.8703, 0.95441, 0.95441, 0.95441, 0.95441, 0.98481, 
0.99697), B03_Red_pvalSpear = c(0.016667, 0.23333, 0.23333, 0.23333, 
0.23333, 0.083333, 0.016667, 0.016667, 0.016667, 0.083333, 0.016667, 
0.016667, 0.016667, 0.016667, 0.016667, 0.016667, 0.016667, 0.016667, 
0.016667, 0.016667, 0.016667, 0.016667, 0.016667, 0.016667, 0.016667, 
0.083333, 0.083333, 4.9603e-05, 0.0027778, 0.0082672, 0.0045635, 
0.0027778, 0.0045635, 0.0030754, 0.0027778, 0.0027778, 6.5789e-05, 
0.0027778, 0.00039683, 8.7315e-07, 8.7315e-07, 8.7315e-07, 8.7315e-07, 
8.7315e-07, 8.7315e-07, 0.00039683, 0.0027778, 0.0027778, 0.006746, 
0.0027778, 0.0027778, 0.016667, 0.0027778, 0.0027778, 1.0163e-05, 
0.0015278, 0.0022738, 1.7883e-05, 1.7883e-05, 1.7883e-05, 1.7883e-05, 
2.2888e-07, 3.6981e-10), B04_RE1_Rho = c(0.71429, 0.7, 0.7, 0.7, 
0.7, 0.7, 0.82857, 0.82857, 0.82857, 0.9, 0.94286, 0.94286, 0.82857, 
0.94286, 0.82857, 0.82857, 0.94286, 0.78269, 0.82857, 0.94286, 
0.94286, 0.71429, 0.94286, 0.94286, 1, 0.7, 0.9, 0.75, 1, 0.51667, 
0.64286, 1, 0.61905, 0.41667, 0.96429, 1, 0.85356, 0.96429, 0.83333, 
0.81459, 0.80851, 0.90578, 0.97873, 0.89362, 0.97873, 1, 0.96429, 
1, 1, 0.96429, 0.92857, 0.94286, 0.96429, 0.96429, 0.76596, 0.74164, 
0.72804, 0.80244, 0.71125, 0.83283, 0.83283, 0.80244, 0.83283
), B04_RE1_pvalSpear = c(0.13611, 0.23333, 0.23333, 0.23333, 
0.23333, 0.23333, 0.058333, 0.058333, 0.058333, 0.083333, 0.016667, 
0.016667, 0.058333, 0.016667, 0.058333, 0.058333, 0.016667, 0.065704, 
0.058333, 0.016667, 0.016667, 0.13611, 0.016667, 0.016667, 0.0027778, 
0.23333, 0.083333, 0.025491, 0.00039683, 0.1618, 0.096181, 0.00039683, 
0.11498, 0.26958, 0.0027778, 0.00039683, 0.0034182, 0.0027778, 
0.015377, 0.0041061, 0.0046353, 0.00030732, 8.7315e-07, 0.00049187, 
8.7315e-07, 0.00039683, 0.0027778, 0.00039683, 0.00039683, 0.0027778, 
0.006746, 0.016667, 0.0027778, 0.0027778, 0.009787, 0.014075, 
0.026154, 0.0052115, 0.021091, 0.0027779, 0.0027779, 0.0052115, 
0.0027779), B05_RE2_Rho = c(0.37143, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 
0.14286, 0.085714, 0.31429, 0.5, 0.37143, 0.37143, 0.31429, 0.37143, 
0.31429, -0.028989, 0.31429, 0.31429, 0.31429, 0.37143, 0.37143, 
0.31429, 0.37143, 0.37143, 0.42857, 0.1, 0.2, 0.11667, 0.82143, 
0.11667, 0.38095, 0.82143, 0.38095, 0.10042, 0.46429, 0.82143, 
0.56067, 0.82143, 0.33333, 0.10334, 0.15806, 0.54711, 0.91794, 
0.62805, 0.8997, 0.82143, 0.75, 0.82143, 0.82143, 0.53571, 0.75, 
0.94286, 0.75, 0.82143, -0.16413, -0.042553, 0.14226, 0.22493, 
-0.030395, 0.16413, 0.22493, 0.12766, 0.20061), B05_RE2_pvalSpear = c(0.49722, 
0.78333, 0.78333, 0.78333, 0.78333, 0.78333, 0.80278, 0.91944, 
0.56389, 0.45, 0.49722, 0.49722, 0.56389, 0.49722, 0.56389, 0.95653, 
0.56389, 0.56389, 0.56389, 0.49722, 0.49722, 0.56389, 0.49722, 
0.49722, 0.41944, 0.95, 0.78333, 0.77563, 0.034127, 0.77563, 
0.35987, 0.034127, 0.35987, 0.79714, 0.30238, 0.034127, 0.11633, 
0.034127, 0.42788, 0.77633, 0.66276, 0.10168, 0.00017953, 0.051847, 
0.00039167, 0.034127, 0.06627, 0.034127, 0.034127, 0.23571, 0.06627, 
0.016667, 0.06627, 0.034127, 0.65047, 0.90708, 0.71503, 0.53212, 
0.93357, 0.65047, 0.53212, 0.72525, 0.57841), B06_RE3_Rho = c(0.085714, 
-0.1, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.085714, 0.085714, 0.085714, 0.2, 
0.37143, 0.31429, 0.31429, 0.31429, 0.31429, 0.085714, 0.31429, 
0.37143, -0.14286, 0.37143, 0.31429, 0.085714, 0.37143, 0.31429, 
0.31429, 0.1, 0.1, 0.11667, 0.67857, 0.11667, 0.38095, 0.75, 
0.33333, 0.083333, 0.32143, 0.67857, 0.35984, 0.53571, 0.33333, 
-0.018237, 0.13374, 0.40122, 0.68293, 0.5228, 0.77812, 0.67857, 
0.46429, 0.67857, 0.67857, 0.39286, 0.67857, 0.82857, 0.75, 0.67857, 
-0.17629, -0.1155, 0.092051, -0.042553, -0.054711, -0.018237, 
0.17629, 0.042553, 0.17629), B06_RE3_pvalSpear = c(0.91944, 0.95, 
0.78333, 0.78333, 0.78333, 0.78333, 0.91944, 0.91944, 0.91944, 
0.78333, 0.49722, 0.56389, 0.56389, 0.56389, 0.56389, 0.91944, 
0.56389, 0.49722, 0.80278, 0.49722, 0.56389, 0.91944, 0.49722, 
0.56389, 0.56389, 0.95, 0.95, 0.77563, 0.10952, 0.77563, 0.35987, 
0.06627, 0.42788, 0.84318, 0.49762, 0.10952, 0.34151, 0.23571, 
0.42788, 0.96012, 0.71262, 0.2505, 0.029517, 0.12103, 0.0080331, 
0.10952, 0.30238, 0.10952, 0.10952, 0.39563, 0.10952, 0.058333, 
0.06627, 0.10952, 0.62612, 0.75068, 0.81379, 0.90708, 0.88068, 
0.96012, 0.62612, 0.90708, 0.62612), B07_BNR_Rho = c(0.37143, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.085714, 0.085714, 0.31429, 0.2, 0.31429, 
0.31429, 0.31429, 0.31429, 0.31429, 0.085714, 0.085714, 0.31429, 
0.085714, 0.31429, 0.31429, 0.085714, 0.31429, 0.31429, -0.25714, 
0.2, 0.2, 0.33333, 0.75, 0.083333, 0.33333, 0.75, 0.28571, 0.2, 
0.67857, 0.67857, 0.6862, 0.32143, 0.33333, 0.44817, 0.32219, 
0.69909, 0.87538, 0.87538, 0.87538, 0.75, 0.53571, 0.75, 0.75, 
0.32143, 0.75, 0.94286, 0.67857, 0.67857, 0.37082, 0.054711, 
0.10879, 0.17629, 0.34651, 0.41945, 0.62006, 0.34651, 0.31003
), B07_BNR_pvalSpear = c(0.49722, 0.78333, 0.78333, 0.78333, 
0.78333, 0.78333, 0.91944, 0.91944, 0.56389, 0.78333, 0.56389, 
0.56389, 0.56389, 0.56389, 0.56389, 0.91944, 0.91944, 0.56389, 
0.91944, 0.56389, 0.56389, 0.91944, 0.56389, 0.56389, 0.65833, 
0.78333, 0.78333, 0.38532, 0.06627, 0.84318, 0.42788, 0.06627, 
0.50079, 0.6134, 0.10952, 0.10952, 0.041242, 0.49762, 0.42788, 
0.19395, 0.36393, 0.024471, 0.00090533, 0.00090533, 0.00090533, 
0.06627, 0.23571, 0.06627, 0.06627, 0.49762, 0.06627, 0.016667, 
0.10952, 0.10952, 0.29147, 0.88068, 0.78055, 0.62612, 0.32666, 
0.22755, 0.055823, 0.32666, 0.38332), B08_NIR_Rho = c(-0.31429, 
-0.5, -0.1, 0.2, -0.1, -0.1, -0.31429, -0.14286, -0.14286, 0.1, 
0.085714, -0.14286, -0.14286, -0.14286, -0.14286, -0.71429, -0.14286, 
-0.14286, -0.71429, -0.14286, -0.14286, -0.14286, -0.31429, -0.14286, 
-0.6, -0.3, -0.4, -0.15, 0.25, -0.23333, 0.047619, 0.32143, -0.11905, 
-0.23333, -0.14286, 0.32143, -0.083683, 0.21429, -0.02381, -0.17021, 
-0.22493, 0.27964, 0.43769, 0.16413, 0.51672, 0.32143, 0.071429, 
0.32143, 0.32143, 0.27028, 0.28571, 0.82857, 0.32143, 0.32143, 
-0.41338, -0.29787, -0.058578, -0.10334, -0.16413, -0.15198, 
-0.10334, -0.1155, -0.024316), B08_NIR_pvalSpear = c(0.56389, 
0.45, 0.95, 0.78333, 0.95, 0.95, 0.56389, 0.80278, 0.80278, 0.95, 
0.91944, 0.80278, 0.80278, 0.80278, 0.80278, 0.13611, 0.80278, 
0.80278, 0.13611, 0.80278, 0.80278, 0.80278, 0.56389, 0.80278, 
0.24167, 0.68333, 0.51667, 0.70807, 0.59484, 0.55171, 0.93487, 
0.49762, 0.79301, 0.55171, 0.78254, 0.49762, 0.83051, 0.66151, 
0.97679, 0.63826, 0.53212, 0.43393, 0.20585, 0.65047, 0.1262, 
0.49762, 0.90635, 0.49762, 0.49762, 0.55773, 0.55595, 0.058333, 
0.49762, 0.49762, 0.23506, 0.4032, 0.88101, 0.77633, 0.65047, 
0.67512, 0.77633, 0.75068, 0.94684), B09_SW1_Rho = c(-0.88571, 
-1, -1, -0.9, -0.9, -0.9, -0.88571, -0.88571, -0.84067, -0.9, 
-0.88571, -0.88571, -0.88571, -0.88571, -0.88571, -0.94286, -0.88571, 
-0.88571, -0.94286, -0.88571, -0.94286, -0.88571, -0.88571, -0.88571, 
-0.88571, -0.9, -0.9, -0.93333, -0.92857, -0.95, -0.95238, -0.92857, 
-0.92857, -0.95, -0.92857, -0.92857, -0.8703, -0.89286, -0.95238, 
-0.89362, -0.92402, -0.84499, -0.7842, -0.83283, -0.7842, -0.92857, 
-0.96429, -0.89286, -0.89286, -0.82143, -0.71429, -0.31429, -0.85714, 
-0.78571, -0.92402, -0.91794, -0.88704, -0.91794, -0.8997, -0.8997, 
-0.91794, -0.87538, -0.8693), B09_SW1_pvalSpear = c(0.033333, 
0.016667, 0.016667, 0.083333, 0.083333, 0.083333, 0.033333, 0.033333, 
0.036058, 0.083333, 0.033333, 0.033333, 0.033333, 0.033333, 0.033333, 
0.016667, 0.033333, 0.033333, 0.016667, 0.033333, 0.016667, 0.033333, 
0.033333, 0.033333, 0.033333, 0.083333, 0.083333, 0.00074956, 
0.006746, 0.00035273, 0.0011409, 0.006746, 0.0022321, 0.00035273, 
0.006746, 0.006746, 0.0022738, 0.012302, 0.0011409, 0.00049187, 
0.00013295, 0.0020858, 0.0072455, 0.0027779, 0.0072455, 0.006746, 
0.0027778, 0.012302, 0.012302, 0.034127, 0.088095, 0.56389, 0.02381, 
0.048016, 0.00013295, 0.00017953, 0.001426, 0.00017953, 0.00039167, 
0.00039167, 0.00017953, 0.00090533, 0.001087), B10_SW2_Rho = c(-0.88571, 
-1, -1, -0.9, -1, -1, -0.94286, -0.88571, -0.88571, -0.9, -0.77143, 
-0.88571, -0.88571, -0.88571, -0.88571, -0.94286, -0.88571, -0.88571, 
-0.94286, -0.88571, -0.94286, -0.88571, -0.88571, -0.88571, -0.71429, 
-1, -1, -0.96667, -0.92857, -0.96235, -0.95238, -0.92857, -0.97008, 
-0.95, -1, -0.92857, -0.80335, -0.89286, -0.97619, -0.90578, 
-0.92402, -0.8693, -0.65046, -0.85107, -0.72341, -0.92857, -0.89286, 
-0.89286, -0.71429, -0.82143, -0.71429, -0.31429, -0.85714, -0.67857, 
-0.92402, -0.88754, -0.8703, -0.93617, -0.85715, -0.87538, -0.93617, 
-0.87538, -0.82675), B10_SW2_pvalSpear = c(0.033333, 0.016667, 
0.016667, 0.083333, 0.016667, 0.016667, 0.016667, 0.033333, 0.033333, 
0.083333, 0.10278, 0.033333, 0.033333, 0.033333, 0.033333, 0.016667, 
0.033333, 0.033333, 0.016667, 0.033333, 0.016667, 0.033333, 0.033333, 
0.033333, 0.13611, 0.016667, 0.016667, 0.00016534, 0.006746, 
3.2859e-05, 0.0011409, 0.006746, 6.5486e-05, 0.00035273, 0.00039683, 
0.006746, 0.0091064, 0.012302, 0.00039683, 0.00030732, 0.00013295, 
0.001087, 0.041705, 0.0017911, 0.018048, 0.006746, 0.012302, 
0.012302, 0.088095, 0.034127, 0.088095, 0.56389, 0.02381, 0.10952, 
0.00013295, 0.00060967, 0.0022738, 6.7189e-05, 0.0015278, 0.00090533, 
6.7189e-05, 0.00090533, 0.0031797)), row.names = c(NA, -63L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Why not solve it with a bit of data wrangling? E.g. create a new data frame via `group_by` "bracket", `summarize` the number of observations `n()` and plot them right above your chart in the middle of the "bracket"?